# print some particular character from given string in c

Tags: c, string

I need to print particular character from given string for example the given string is `"always god is great god bless you"`.

I need print `god`.

It may be found number of times so I want to print that n times and also I want to print till some specific location from `god`.

I tried to do it using the following program, but do not get my expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j;
    char name[10];
    printf("enter the string\n");

    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        scanf("%c",&name[i]);

    printf("ur entered string is:");

    for(j=0 ; j<=10 ; j++)
        while(name[j] == 'g');
        {
         for(j=0 ; j<=5 ; j++)
             printf("%c",name[j]);
        }
}
```

Comment: lots of error in small code, voting for close!

Comment: `i=0; i<=10` should be `i<10`. also why `j=0; j<=5`? "god" has 3 letters, why getting 6? and you will encounter 'g' in "great" also. Your code doesn't even try to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to declaration `char name[10];`, you have array out of bound bug:

```
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
         ^^^^^   should be < 10
```

Undefined behavior.

Instead of `if` you have used `while`(semicolon ; after while ) and to print `5` time the inner loop counter should be different (not `j`).

Btw, for string `"always god is great god bless you".`  10 char array is small.

Comment: thank you sir...i'll try it...but i gave within 10 char array only while i am giving input...

Comment: @user3202243 for 10th char max index is 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use strstr() function to find specific string from a bigger string. Your code is modified according to the function but this way, you would only input a string of 12 characters only.

```
int main(void)
{
   char str[12], *ext="God",*srch;
   int i;
   printf("enter the string\n");
   for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
   scanf("%c",&str[i]);
   srch=strstr(str,ext);
   if(srch!=NULL)
   for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
   printf("%c", srch[i]);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: yeah i try it.but actually i write this program for microcontroller so some controller may not accept the string function...